# How do I draw a horizontal line independent for each subplot? (Also issues with shared axes)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create several subplots dynamically and want to display the average of each column with the subplots. I also want to display the min and max values in each subplot. This should happen in the form of the horizontal line of plotly. Unfortunately, I don't know how and whether to create the horizontal line dynamically for each subplot.

This is the function to create the subplots with average values:

```py
    def calculate_avergae(df: pd.DataFrame) -> px.bar:
    """Calculates the average values of numeric columns in a dataframe. Gives back a plotly bar chart with multiplie subplots.

    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): Dataframe to calculate the average values of numeric columns.

    Returns:
        px.bar: Plotly bar chart with multiplie subplots.
    """
    bad_column_str = ["_id", "id_", "_id_", " id ", " id", "id "]
    numeric_columns = cl.get_numeric_columns(df)
    numeric_columns = cl.remove_columns_containing_str(numeric_columns, bad_column_str)

    subplot_cols = math.ceil(numeric_columns.__len__() / 4)
    fig_mean = make_subplots(
        rows=subplot_cols,
        cols=4,
        shared_xaxes=False,
        shared_yaxes=False,
    )

    for i, col in enumerate(numeric_columns):
        for k in range(0, subplot_cols):
            fig_mean.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[col], y=[df[col].mean()]), row=k + 1, col=i + 1)
            create_min_ruler(df, numeric_columns, fig_mean)
            create_max_ruler(df, numeric_columns, fig_mean)

    fig_mean.update_layout(
        template="plotly_white",
        title_text="Average values of numeric columns",
        height=400,
    )
    return fig_mean
```

This is the function for creatin a min horizontal line:

```py
def create_min_ruler(df: pd.DataFrame, numeric_columns: List[str], fig):
    """Creates a ruler for the minimum values of numeric columns in a dataframe. The ruler is added to a plotly figure.

    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): Dataframe to calculate the minimum values of numeric columns.
        numeric_columns (List[str]): List of numeric columns in the dataframe.
        fig (plotly figure): Plotly figure to add the ruler to.

    Returns:
        plotly figure: Plotly figure with the ruler added.
    """
    min_values = {}
    for col in numeric_columns:
        df.sort_values(by=col, ascending=True, inplace=True)
        head = df[col].iloc[0]
        min_values[col] = head

    for key, value in min_values.items():
        fig.add_hline(y=value, annotation_text=f"Min value of {key}", annotation_position="bottom left")
    return fig
```

And this is how the output looks like:

[image]

I have also the problem, that the plots share the same y-axes. First I enapled the option. Now I disabled it, but it's still there. I restarted the kernel, reinstalled the package but nothing works. I'm working with poetry, pyhton3.8.